# I am trying to perform a machine learning analyis using the ArcGIS module in Jupyter notebooks but strange error

Tags: arcgis-python-api, jupyter-notebook, machine-learning

I was trying to import all modules for ArcGIS to perform a machine learning analysis. However, the code gives me an error at the line from arcgis.learn.

Code:

```
%matplotlib inline

import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from IPython.display import Image
from IPython.display import HTML
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from datetime import datetime as dt

import arcgis
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.learn import MLModel, prepare_tabulardata
from arcgis.raster import Raster

from fastai.vision import *
```

Error:

> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 12 import arcgis
> 13 from arcgis.gis import GIS
> ---> 14 from arcgis.learn import MLModel, prepare_tabulardata
> 15 from arcgis.raster import Raster
> 16
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\prj\lib\site-packages\arcgis\learn_*init*_.py in
>
> 15
> 16 if not _LAMBDA_TEXT_CLASSIFICATION:
> ---> 17     from .models import (
> 18         SingleShotDetector,
> 19         UnetClassifier,
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\prj\lib\site-packages\arcgis\learn\models_*init*_.py
> in 
> 2
> 3 if not _LAMBDA_TEXT_CLASSIFICATION:
> ----> 4     from ._ssd import SingleShotDetector
> 5     from ._unet import UnetClassifier
> 6     from ._retinanet import RetinaNet
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\prj\lib\site-packages\arcgis\learn\models_ssd.py in
>
> ----> 1 from ._arcgis_model import ArcGISModel, _get_device
> 2 from pathlib import Path
> 3 import json
> 4 from ._codetemplate import code
> 5 import warnings
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\prj\lib\site-packages\arcgis\learn\models_arcgis_model.py
> in 
> 33     if not _LAMBDA_TEXT_CLASSIFICATION:
> 34         from fastai.vision.learner import model_meta, _default_meta
> ---> 35         from .._utils.common import get_post_processed_model
> 36         from torchvision import models
> 37
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\prj\lib\site-packages\arcgis\learn_utils\common.py
> in 
> 125
> 126
> --> 127 class ArcGISMSImage(Image):
> 128     def show(
> 129         self, ax=None, rgb_bands=None, show_axis=False, title=None, return_ax=False
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\prj\lib\site-packages\arcgis\learn_utils\common.py
> in ArcGISMSImage()
> 180
> 181     @classmethod
> --> 182     def open(cls, path, cast_to=np.float32, div=None, imagery_type=None):
> 183         path = str(os.path.abspath(path))
> 184         if not os.path.exists:
>
> NameError: name 'np' is not defined

What is wrong because I am not using numpy here and it's not needed!

Comment: Since ArcPy is very dependent on numpy, I imagine that the error is coming from a library dependency.

Comment: So what do I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check and make sure your conda is up to date. If you go into cmd then type in

> where conda

it will let you know if you at least have it installed somewhere.

Comment: Conda is up to date but same issue

Comment: Have you run this yet to get esri module installed? conda install arcgis -c esri

Comment: The first part of the error message is what's making me think it may be a gis module issue. Also, have you tried running these imports in a different IDE? Like one that is connected to ArcPro, such as Spyder or Jupyter Notebooks?

Comment: Also, you could just try and import numpy, even if it seems you won't be using it. Wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Yes I am running this in jupyter notebook and have installed everything 
If I remove the arcgis.learn line then it works

Comment: I tried numpy still not working